# What is the term meaning calling a character by a described trait?

Tags: characters, description, terminology

What is the technique called when a writer describes a character and from there forward refers to that character by one of their salient traits? For example, "The man across from her took in the subway car with bulging, frog-like eyes. ... Frog Eyes reached for the cable."

Comment: It's called metonymy.

Comment: Thanks! That's it.